# Посоветуйте систему контроля версий

Tags: контроль-версий

Ищу систему контроля версий с локальным сервером для хранения бинарников.

Ключевое требование: при помещении/извлечении файла дата файла не должна меняться. Т.е. создали файл 1 сентября, 2 сентября закомитили, 3 сентября сделали checkout - на локальном компьютере должен образоваться файл с датой 1 сентября

Еще нужно branch и merge веток. Т.к. файлы все бинарные, то merge самих файлов делать не нужно. Разрешение конфликтов вручную

Смотрю на SVN - он извлекает файлы с датой коммита. Что не то

Answer (score 4):

[Mercurial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial) имеет такую фичу - он сохраняет не время коммита, а время модификации файла. Смотрите на [TimestampModExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TimestampModExtension)

**дисклеймер:** сам никогда не пробовал, но судя по описанию как раз то, чего вы хотите.

Comment: Похоже. Спасибо